# Simulink function improper response

Tags: matlab, simulink, differential-equations

I'm using the simulink function block to simulate the differential equation `xdot = -x+x^2`
And at the same time, I'm generating the same function manually, using a multiplier and a comparator. 
both simulations use an integrator block to compute the derivative xdot where the initial condition of the integrator is set to an interval `[-0.5:0.5:0.5]`.

I can not figure out why I'm getting different responses from these similar simulations ? notice that the manually build simulation response is the right one.

Here is the simulink model:  [diff equa model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5aPxuMLmixfLW0zb2VKQUktMUU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you post what's in that link you referenced to the question itself?

Comment: Ok, I watched your model and can't see any noise blocks or smth that has different values in different simulations... maybe I understood smth in wrong way?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam: Do you mean you're getting the same curves in the two scopes ? I don't! Please tell me which Matlab version you're using ?

Comment: @Dethariel : The model file is download-able from my Google drive account using that link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5aPxuMLmixfLW0zb2VKQUktMUU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AHA! I got this. Look at this (it's the simulation at the first timestep): [image]
Now we can see the problem - `Fcn` block don't understand, that `u` is a vector! So it works with the first element of your vector only!

I found this strange and check in help: [matlab official](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fcn.html).
And we can see this:

> u — The input to the block. If u is a vector, u(i) represents the ith
>   element of the vector; u(1) or u alone represents the first element.

So. I think bottom part of the model works like you want!